# YA novel about a girl who gets caught stealing, and then has to deal with the social consequences

Tags: identification-request

I was explaining the concept of a Problem Novel to someone, when I suddenly had vivid memories of another one that I read when I was a child. The basic plot of it was that a young woman, probably somewhere in the teenage range, gets caught stealing, probably shoplifting. Due to her age, she doesn't face prison time, but is of course under a lot of distrust from people around her. Somewhere later in the book, she gets a job as a babysitter for at least one young boy - I remember a scene where she's giving him a bath, and he comments about having a penis, and how "whales don't have penises", something which stuck in my head, because, in talking with my parents about the book, I found out I've been mispronouncing that word wrong - and seems to be on the way to getting her life back, when something in the house comes up missing, I think maybe a set of earrings owned by the mother of the kids that she is babysitting, and she is of course suspected due to her history. Eventually, she is vindicated.

I remember the cover having a fairly realistic image of the girl in question, possibly a photograph showing her in the middle of shoplifting, and the title was something about her being a thief, like "I Was a Teenage Thief" . I remember that, at the time, I was excited about the prospect of reading it, because my experiences with *Dungeons and Dragons* had left me with a favorable impression of thieves. Looking back on it, I wonder if my parents steered me towards the book to get me to understand that stealing was not a good thing, let alone a viable career prospect.

I probably read it somewhere in the early 90s, as a library book checked out in Ashland, KY. In my memories, it was a full-sized hardback book, and I was reading that like the book at the time, but I don't entirely trust my memories, as what I remember of the plot feels a lot shorter than that.

Comment: So what career path _did_ you choose?

Comment: Probably not any of [these](https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/shoplifting) or [these](https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/76351.Teenage_Kleptomaniacs)?

Comment: @SQB: Software. :-D I don't honestly know if it's a more ethical path...

Comment: @Randal'Thor: Actually... one of those looks very familiar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rand al'Thor provided a Goodreads list of [Teenage Kleptomaniacs](https://www.goodreads.com/list/show/76351.Teenage_Kleptomaniacs), and the title and image of one of the books jumped out at me, *[Angel Baker, Thief](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1302249.Angel_Baker_Thief)* by Jeannette Eyerly.

[image: Front cover of Angel Baker, Thief]

> Fifteen-year-old Angel, released on probation to a foster family after being convicted of shoplifting, is anxious to make a fresh start and to be accepted by her new family and friends.

It's a hardcover book of over 200 pages, the cover uses a photograph, and "Thief" is prominent in the title (and in red, something that I was considering adding, except that it was a very vague memory). The Internet Archive [has a copy](https://archive.org/details/angelbakerthief00eyer/), and the little boy apparently pretended he was a fish so that he wouldn't be concerned about Angela seeing his penis.

> Crom, also, after refusing that first night to let Angela help him with his bath — the reason, he said, was "I don't want you to see my penis" — relented when she told him about her little brother. "When I help give Jonah a bath," she said, "we pretend he's a fish, and then when he is all nice and clean and through swimming, I catch him up with a big towel and say, as I wipe him, 'Who ever saw a fish with curly hair? Who ever saw a fish with arms or a belly button?"
>
> "Or a fish with a penis," squealed Crom as, getting into the spirit of the thing, he began to peel off his clothes.

It was apparently a "scholarship key" that went missing which, as it turns out, was stolen by Crom, although he claimed that his imaginary friend Giggles did the crime.

> Mrs. Gardiner, while cleaning out the toy chest in the playroom after the close of school, had found the missing gold scholarship key fastened to a piece of string and draped, watch-chain fashion, around the fat middle of Mr. Hawkins, Crom's one-armed teddy bear. "As neither his father nor I," wrote Mrs. Gardiner, "think it would serve any useful purpose at this late date to punish Crom for lying to us — even after all this time he continues to say Giggles is the culprit — we have insisted his invisible playmate take a nice long trip somewhere and not come back."

Comment: As a side note, I cannot help but wonder if the Gardiners were big Robert E. Howard fans, given Crom's name...