# What's on the pages missing from the Internet Archive copy of "Angel Baker, Thief"?

Tags: misprint

Borrowed the [Internet Archive's copy](https://archive.org/details/angelbakerthief00eyer) of "Angel Baker, Thief", because [the blurbs](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/24307/566) had me confused about how the fostering system worked, which, by the by, is that Angel(a) is a kleptomanic, and been taken from her mother into a group home for rehabilitation. That's how she's in a legal state to be fostered.

In any case, the Internet Archive copy is missing the numbered pages before page 4, which starts with:

> You never do! You're Miss Perfect Angel. Miss Golden Girl. Miss Good-goody. What are you doing at Meadowbrook, then, along with all the rest of us thieves and prostitutes?"
>
> "I didn't mean I hadn't *ever*," Angela replied, [...] to Rosie Callan

But what's *before* that, but after the prologue? It basically can't be nothing, since that first line is dialogue that starts mid-way, having a dangling quotation mark after "prostitutes?"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Examining the physical copy in my library, I found that the table of contents ends on page *viii* and a short prologue appears on pages *ix* and *x*.

The story itself begins on page 3. The first chapter is titled *Miss Perfect Angel*.

> She was hurrying down Meadowbrook's hall on her way to typing--there's so [sic] such thing as summer vacation at a training school--when Rosie Callan came up behind her and in a hissing voice said, "Hey, Baker. The Fingers wants to see you. Right now. Pronto. She sent me to tell you."
>
> Because Rosie Callan was a troublemaker and the biggest liar in the whole school, Angela went on walking.
>
> "Listen," Rosie said. "I'm not kidding. She really does want to see you. If you don't go, you'll be in for it. You may be in for it anyway, for all I know."
>
> "But I haven't done anything," Angela faltered. But even then she was beginning to wonder. Rosie Callan could make you feel as if you'd killed somebody when all you were doing was biting your fingernails.
>
> "'Haven't done anything'!" Rosie parroted the words jeeringly before allowing her voice to return to its usual whine. "Oh, no! You haven't done anything!

<sub>Eyerly. (1984). *Angel Baker, Thief.* p. 3</sub>

Comment: Nicely done shoover ! 

Answer (score 2):

Examining the internet archive copy to which you refer and by examining the 'contents' page The prologue starts on page ix ,by leafing through the pages online : it can be seen that the prologue begins on page ix , and ends overleaf on page x .

Now odd numbered pages lie on the right and even numbered ones on left (by convention).Therefore the un-numbered page bearing the title 'Book I'  must needs be page 1 .Overleaf is the other side -which would be blank page 2 ,  and facing page 2 is page 3 : which the table of contents give as the first page of the  first chapter of Book 1 : titled 'Miss Perfect Angel' in the contents It is barely discernable  in larger font through page 1 , and below this chapter title on same page is unreadable obscure smaller font text of the first page i.e 3(sadly all missing ) .

Then again  page  4 ( clearlyly readable ) is the second page of chapter 1,where the book continues with text having end quotation marks, but no commencement quotation marks which is evidence again of the missing page 3 ( as you helpfully point out in the comments Malady).

So what is missing in its entriety is page 3.The start page of the first chapter in book 1 has a ghostly image of a page of text (sadly unreadable and unclear) which represents page 3.
Crossing over into the mysterious imaginary spirit realm of dead pages in search of our ghost might be one approach, but more practical and certain was to review an existing physical copy and extract page 3 as below.

> ```
>                 Miss Perfect Angel
> ```
>
> She was hurrying down Meadowbrook's hall on her way to typing-
> -there's no such thing as summer vacation at a training school--when Rosie Callan came up behind her and in a hissing voice said, "Hey, Baker.The Fingers wants to see you. Right now. Pronto. She sent me to
> tell you."
>
> Because Rosie Callan was a troublemaker and the biggest liar in the whole school, Angela went on walking.
> "Listen," Rosie said. "I'm not kidding. She really does want to see you. If you don't go, you'll be in for it. You may be in for it anyway, for all I know."
>
> "But I haven't done anything," Angela faltered. But even then she was beginning to wonder. Rosie Callan could make you feel as if you'd killed somebody when all you were doing was biting your fingernails.
>
> ""Haven't done anything'!" Rosie parroted the words jeeringly before allowing her voice to return to its usual whine. "Oh, no! You haven't done anything!

Extracted from p3 of Angel Baker, Thief : Jeanette Eyerly ,
1984 ( Lippincott Williams & Wilkins )

Comment: I don't think this can be correct, since (i) Book II has a heading on page 45 and text on page 47, so Book I which has a heading on page 1 ought to have text on page 3. (ii) It is possible to see through the scan of page 1 and make out a block of text that must be on page 3, though I find it too faint to make out any words; (iii) It is (just!) possible to see though the scan of page 4 where there are gaps and make out some of the text on page 3. For example, I can make out "cation at a training school" in the space to the right of "Wilma Goss".

Comment: @Gareth Rees : too true , there is a ghostly image ( of page 3 ) , barely visible on page 1 ,which has been omitted .Ive emailed the internet archive awaiting a response : unsure of the latency prior to corrective action .

Comment: @schweppz Let us know how you get on, I'd be interested to hear about the process.

Comment: Re the process of lodging the enquiry on the help pages an email address is given : infor@archive.org .                                                                                                             
 Sadly , I have a response : it is both short and dissapointing to quote  " Thanks for contacting us.
 
Unfortunately we have no way to check the physical copy or make changes or corrections. "

Comment: Curiously "Agent saphire" the pseudonym on my email response from internet archive has posted a review on internet archive for this book stating " item incomplete missing page 3 " .

Comment: Oh, so your version fixed the "there's so [sic] such"!